# Spring 4 @Transactional doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-data

I have a Spring 4.3 Application with simple configuration and I expect my methods from service classes to be transactional so I enable transaction management in my configuration and then annotate my service methods with @Transactional. I call service methods from my controlles but they don't behave as expected. When some part of a method throws exception rollback is never called

AppInitializer.class:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

RootConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages"package.repository"})
public class RootConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ...
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        ...
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        ...
        return factory.getObject();
    }
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }
}
```

Does anybody have idea what is wrong here

GitHub link https://github.com/VadOs1/TRANSACTIONAL-ISSUE/

Thanks

Comment: add the configuration of the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. Add actual configuration not templates as you are basically posting an incomplete picture. Show the code that isn't working (the service or whatever class yu have with `@Transactional`. Next to that the `@Enable*` annotation have to be on `@COnfiguration` classes currently your `@EnableTransactionManagement` doesn't do anything move it to `RootConfig`. Also why does your root config not contain a `@ComponentScan` is that by any change on `WebConfig`?

Comment: https://github.com/VadOs1/TRANSACTIONAL-ISSUE/

Comment: Your configuration is quite a mess. The `@ComponentScan` that is on your `MainController` must go on the `RootConfig`. The fact that transactions don't work is because of your flawed configuration. To apply transactions spring used AOP, AOP only applies to beans in the **same** application context. The transactional aspect is loaded by the root context (`ContextLoaderListener`) while the beans you want to be transactional are loaded by the child context (`DispatcherServlet`) so no AOP and thus transactions will be applied.

Comment: moving all component scan to root config except controller package which is in web config solved the issue. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you remove the @EnableTransactionManagement annotation from the AppInitializer class and enable it in RootConfig class and let me know if this worked for you

ie

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages"package.repository"})
public class RootConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ...
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        ...
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        ...
        return factory.getObject();
    }
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have try/catch statement in the method that rollback is never called?